# How to install postgresSQL-10 from binaries on ubuntu 18

Tags: postgresql

I downloaded tar file from postgres site [here](https://www.enterprisedb.com/download-postgresql-binaries), and followed next step from this document [here](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/04/linux-postgresql-install-and-configure-from-source/) and facing this issue

```
./configure :command not found
```

Comment: Those instructions are nine years old, that was unwise. Ubuntu 18.04 already has packages for PGS 10 - what's wrong with simply using those?

Comment: i'm just curious and interested to find the ways of installation